# Installing Rails 3.0.7 on Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, ubuntu-10.10

Having some real difficulty setting up my RoR envirionment in Ubuntu 10.10

Installed RVM with ruby 1.9.2

```
ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [i686-linux]
```

and i have ruby gems setup

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.6.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 180) [i686-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/toast/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/toast/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/toast/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/toast/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180
     - /home/toast/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Now when it came to installing Rails i had all sorts of difficulties but now it seems to install:

```
    $ sudo gem install rails
Successfully installed rails-3.0.7
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rails-3.0.7...
Installing RDoc documentation for rails-3.0.7...
```

yet rails commands fail and rails -v results in

```
    The program 'rails' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install rails
```

I'm out of ideas on this one!

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've installed Rails under root user (sudo), and then you are trying to use it under local user. As far as it installed to root user you haven't got `rails` command in your local user `PATH`.

What you can do

1. Add its Path manualy
2. Install it via local user
3. Use [RVM](https://rvm.io)

I prefer to use RVM.

As far as you are using RVM, you don't need to use `sudo`. But when you need it you can use `rvmsudo`, but not in this case. Just

```
gem install rails
```

Comment: many thanks, i used rvm for ruby and when i tried gem install rails i get the following: ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
   ` no such file to load -- zlib
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NameError)
    uninitialized constant Gem::Commands::InstallCommand`

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use *sudo* with RVM.
If you type rvm info, you will see what ruby you use and where are your gems stored.

With sudo, you are probably using system's ruby from Ubuntu package.

Jus try `gem install rails`.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said you need to install rails from gem via

```
gem install rails
```

The other somewhat tricky thing is that when you change into the rails app directory you need to make sure the dependencies are met for that app by doing:

```
bundle install
```

I've gone into a bit more detail on getting Rails 3 set up under Ubuntu at http://blog.dcxn.com/2011/06/21/rolling-with-rails-3-on-ubuntu-11-04/

Good luck!